# Is await blocking the UI thread on android?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

I have been wrapping my head around coroutines and I was wondering about the following code. 
I have the following operation on my **onCreate()**.

```
asyncJob = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val name = async(Dispatchers.Default) { queryDevices() }.await()
    mDeviceName.text = deviceName
}
```

Printing this out the order of execution seems to be before "name" is
on UI thread and after name is set, it is on the UI thread as well. 
The **queryDevicesMethod()** is in a background thread as expected.

But I wanted to know what **await()** is actually doing when calling it on the UI thread?
Is it blocking theUI thread until await returns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Coroutines will not block the thread on suspending. The Kotlin compiler generates a state machine that detaches and attaches the coroutines from the thread, see https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md.

In your case `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)` starts a new coroutine confined to the UI thread. Then `async()` starts a new coroutine confined to another dispatcher. The invocation of `await()` is a suspending function and will detach the first coroutine from the UI thread, waiting for the completion of the `async`-coroutine.

BTW:
You should not use `async` and `await` in one statement. That makes no sense. 
What you really want is to run the `queryDevices()`-function from another dispatcher, but not asynchronously from the perspective of coroutines. In this case you should use [`withContext()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html)

Comment: thanks for that! I am curious about you second point. How come that it does not make sense to have await on one line? I did see android studio suggested using withContext() but I wasn't sure why

Comment: With `async()` you start a new coroutine and it will return a `Deferred`. The `Deferred` has the `await` function to resolve the result of the other coroutine. Typically you use `async/await` to start multiple tasks that should run in parallel. At the end you collect the result of all tasks. The `withContext` function is used to switch the dispatcher/thread for some subtasks, but you still need to run the (sub)tasks sequentially.  Therefor `async/await` in one statement is the same as `withContext`, but does not communicate your intend.